# Excel function to identify dependency of subsequent records

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, powerquery

I am looking for an excel function or formula that allows me to derive the below dependency column. I have a list of processes with start and end time and want to know which subsequent processes fall in between the time interval of any previous processes e.g. Processes E starts at 15:15, while Process D is still running, hence 'E' for the row with Process Id D.

```
Process StartTime EndTime   Dependency
A        12:00    14:00     B,C
B        12:30    13:30     C
C        12:45    14:30 
D        14:45    15:30     E
E        15:15    17:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 Excel, put the following array formula in D2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($B3:$B$7<C2)*($A3:$A$7<>""),$A3:$A$7,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode. Then copy down.

[image]

To make it dynamic on the range we can use INDEX(MATCH()) to automatically set the end cell:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($B3:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A)+1)<C2)*($A3:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)+1)<>""),$A3:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)+1),""))
```

Still an array formula so still needs Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

---

If you do not have Office 365 then you can use this UDF.  Put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```